# How to remove element from 2D array in Rust

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust, rust-ndarray

I need help making sense of Rust's `ndarray` `remove_index()` [function](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.remove_index). For example, I have a 3x3 two dimensional array:

```
use ndarray::{arr2};

let mut arr = arr2([1, 2, 3],
                   [4, 5, 6],
                   [7, 8, 9]);
```

I would like to remove the element with a value `5` at position `[1,1]`. How do I do that with the `remove_index()` function? I don't understand, how do I specify the axes and indices of a 2D array.

```
arr.remove_index(...);
```

Comment: I don't think you _can_ remove a single element like this. As I understand it, the length of the subarrays must all remain the same, so removing 5 would also remove 2 and 8 or 4 and 6 -- you would be removing that entire column or row. If you want a type where each subarray can have a different length, I think you just want a `Vec<Vec<_>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could swap the item to be deleted to the edge:

```
arr.swap([1, 1], [1, 2]); // [1, 2, 3],
                          // [4, 6, 5],
                          // [7, 8, 9]

arr.swap([1, 1], [2, 1]); // [1, 2, 3],
                          // [4, 8, 6],
                          // [7, 5, 9]
```